# Howto block nginx web site access if browsers have no ssl certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, ubuntu-18.04, jupyterhub

I am a newb and i installed jupyterhub with nginx reverse proxy on my ubuntu 18.04 server. I built my own root CA and self signed certificate with openssl. Https connections works very well if my rootCA is installed on my others computers. I want to block access for the computers who don't have my rootCA.
the file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is untouched and my config file /etc/nginx/sites-available/jupyter.conf is:

```
# top-level http config for websocket headers If Upgrade is defined, 
# Connection = upgrade If Upgrade is empty, Connection = close
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}
# HTTP server to redirect all 80 traffic to SSL/HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.4.70 mlserver.net localhost;

    # Tell all requests to port 80 to be 302 redirected to HTTPS
    return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
}
# HTTPS server to handle JupyterHub
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    server_name 192.168.4.70 mlserver.net localhost;
 
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mlserver.net.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/mlserver.net.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    #ssl_stapling on;
 
    # Managing literal requests to the JupyterHub front end
         
        location / {
     
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # websocket headers
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
 
}
```

How can i edit this file to block access for computers who dont have certificate ?
What nginx directive add ?
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to block access for the computers who don't have my rootCA.

This is not possible. The server has no information if the client has successfully validated the server certificate (i.e. clients which have the rootCA) or if a client simply skipped certificate validation (clients which don't have rootCA).

One could try to add a [HSTS header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) so that browsers will not simply allow to ignore certificate problems. But this can also be bypassed on the client side without the server noticing, it just makes it a bit harder.

If you want to control who can access the notebook you would need proper authentication of the clients instead. Knowledge of the rootCA is not client authentication.

Comment: what about if directive or ssl_verify_client ?

Comment: @ArounaN'dia: As I said: *"The server has no information if the client has successfully validated the server certificate"*. This also means that no kind of options on the server side will be able to enforce what you want. As for `ssl_verify_client` - this is about authentication the client side with certificates, which is something completely different from what you ask. Using this would require you to provide your clients with their own certificates (each client gets a different one) and makes them install these in their client.

Comment: i think your last explanation can help me , it is what i want. Provide clients with their own certificates. What config can i do on the server side ? I manage 10 computers and i want only 5 can have an access to the server.

Comment: @ArounaN'dia: this is now a different question then you originally asked and the original one was answered. Please ask a new question if you need to know something different from what you originally asked. But in short: `ssl_verify_client` is the option together with `ssl_trusted_certificate`. See [the documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_verify_client) or [this article](https://fardog.io/blog/2017/12/30/client-side-certificate-authentication-with-nginx/) for more on this.